# Make exec wait for previous exec

Tags: node.js, git, github, webhooks

I'm trying to run `git pull`, `npm run build`, and `pm2 reload myApp` any time something is pushed to my github repo.

I created a server which is connected to github webhooks, and the server runs the following code:

```
const pullFromMaster = exec(`cd ${path} git pull origin master`, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
pullFromMaster.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

pullFromMaster.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Finished Pulling from Github')

    const buildNewCode = exec(`${path} npm run build`, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout)
    });

    buildNewCode.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    buildNewCode.on('end', () => {
        console.log('finished building');
        exec(`pm2 reload ${PM2_IDENTIFIER}`, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('finished reloading server');
            console.log(stdout)
        });
    })
})
```

The problem is the `buildNewCode` process, doesn't wait for `pullFromMaster`, and the `pm2 reload` doesn't wait for `buildNewCode`. How can I make one wait for the next?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+exec+wait

Comment: Can you just use `execSync()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. perfect